# Out-File Won't display all Out-File commands

Tags: powershell, output

I just have a quick question. I want the information I have to print in an text doc. The issue is the only thing I see printing is the one line "No Direct Reports Listed". Why is this so?

```psh
$results = Get-ADUser -Properties enabled,displayname,sn,name,surname `
             -Filter {name -like "*"} |
           Select name,sn,displayname,enabled,surname
$name    = $user.Name
$owned   = Get-Adgroup -Properties description,managedby `
             -Filter {managedby -eq $name}

foreach ($user in $results) {
  if ($user.enabled -eq $false) {
    if ($owned -eq $Null) {
      $user.name + "|" + $user.DisplayName + "|"  +
        "Managing Group: None Found " + "|" +
        " Group Description: None Provided " | Out-File $output
    } elseif (($description -eq " ") -or ($description -eq $Null)) {
      $user.name + "|" + $user.DisplayName + "|"  + "Managing Group: " +
        $_.name + "|" + " Group Description: None Provided " | Out-File $output
    } else {
      $user.name + "|" + $user.DisplayName + "|"  + "Managing Group: " +
        $_.name + "|" + " Group Description: " +
        ($_.description -replace "`r`n", "  ") | Out-File $output
    }

    $directReports = Get-ADUser -Identity $name -Properties directreports |
                     Select -ExpandProperty directreports

    foreach ($ID in $directReports) {
      if ($ID -ne $Null) {
        $directreports = get-aduser $ID
        "Direct Reports Listed Under User: " + "|" + $directreports.name |
          Out-File $output
      } else {
        "No Direct Reports Listed" | Out-File $output
      }
    }#foreach
  }#if
}#foreach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last output in your code, which in this case is `"No Direct Reports Listed" | Out-File $output`, sent to `Out-File` will be what you see in the file. In your current setup you need to use the `-Append` switch. From [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849882.aspx)

> -Append
>
> Adds the output to the end of an existing file, instead of replacing the file contents.

Also you could just use the [`Add-Content`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156791.aspx) cmdlet that does this be default.

Since the encoding is different by default in both `Out-File` and `Add-Content` just be aware that you might need to tweak the `-Encoding` as well.

**Side Note**

Not that it is incredibly complex but when `If` statements start to get out of hand using the [`switch`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730937.aspx) statement can be far more intuitive to handle.

Comment: `switch` is only useful when you need to distinguish between different values/ranges of the same subject. In this case the comparisons have entirely subjects. A more substantial improvement would be to remove the `Out-File` statements from the loops entirly, change the outer loop to a `ForEach-Object` loop, and pipe that into a single `Out-File` statement: `$results | ForEach-Object {...} | Out-File $output`. That would avoid repeated appending to the output file and would thus improve overall performance. Note, however, that `$user` must be replaced with `$_` for this.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Yes what you say about switch is true. In this case I would have used `Switch($true)` to account for that. Also was just trying to answer the question. Been burned trying to optimize code for people in the past a few times.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I am still learning Powershell and honestly never fully knew what -Append did in comparison when it's not used. Now I know so I really appreciate it that you explained.

Comment: Ansgar Wiechers : can you explain how you edited my code to show all the colors? I didn't know you could do that

Comment: @AlyssaCooke [Behold](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting). You could also edit your question to see the current markdown code, or click the "edited XXX ago" link below it to go to the revision history and click "side-by-side markdown" there.